# List of WebElement find by className return Xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I've got multiple div on a webpage that have the same class attribute.
I'm looking for a way to check all the div of my page for a specific class name, and then get, for each of this div, their Xpath.

Actually, i can check how many div i have on the page with a class name :

```
     List<WebElements> test = driver.findElements(By.className("fitter"));
     int countDiv = test.size();
```

Do you have an idea, now, to get all my elements Xpath one by one ? Or have you a different solution ?

My project is a Selenium project and i'm testing a web page. My test are written in Java and i'm using WebDriver.

thanks for help

Comment: you mean you want to automatically get unique `XPath` for each element in list?

Comment: Yes that's it ! I know i can get it directly by.Xpath but the problem is that the number of div is variable. So the unique way to get all of them each time is to get them by class and then get the Xpath to action locally

Comment: `findElements` method should return array of elements. Why don't you just call each of them by index- unique selector for each element?

Comment: It is a dynamical displaying so I don't know how many elements i'm gonna have on my page

Comment: But you can get the number of elements by length of array

Comment: So how can i do to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate through the list of webelements?

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("fitter"));
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    WebElement element = elements.get(i);
    // ... do whatever you need here
}
```

The xpath of each element in the loop would be

```
//div[contains(@class, 'fitter')][i]
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is the " do whatever you need here " ^^ To get for each the Xpath. Can i do a element.getXpath or something ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to extract a xpath for each element individually in the general case. But if you already have the classname, you can use something like  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'fitter')][i]"));`

Comment: So naturally, the xpath for each element is `"//*[contains(@class, 'fitter')][i]"` where i is the loop's control variable. If you only want to focus on divs, then it's `"//div[contains(@class, 'fitter')][i]"`

Comment: @MxfrdA, I have updated the answer to show the xpath that you can use for each element

Comment: Thank, I'll try this and come back to you with the feedback